# css alignment list inside div

Tags: css, layout, text

I'm having lots of problem aligning an image on CSS.
Here is the thing, I have a div called "toggle" inside this div I have a list ul - li on each li I have text and then 3 images, but I want to have the Images aligned some how the alignment of the images are relative to the text not to the left padding.

http://aluna.webdcg.com/visistat/

Comment: `<img>` tags are by default `display:inline;` .. and please , stop using `position: abs/rel;` for creating a layout

Comment: @tereško I think they are `inline-block` by default because you can still adjust the width and height, whilst inline elements dimensions e.g. `span` cannot be manipulated.

Comment: @DexterHuinda , actually **you are be right** .. you can manipulate the height of image tag ..  oh well .. too late to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need. See code in action at: http://jsfiddle.net/67VWe/

CSS:

```
* { font-family: Tahoma; }
ul { width: 200px; margin: 20px; border: 1px solid #777; }
li { padding: 2px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #777; }
li label { width: 120px; float: left; }
​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="toggle">
    <ul>
        <li><label>Text 1</label> <img src="http://admin.visistat.com/sales/img/icon-pulse-dot-red.png" width="22" height="22" /></li>
        <li><label>Text 1234</label> <img src="http://admin.visistat.com/sales/img/icon-pulse-dot-red.png" width="22" height="22" /></li>
        <li><label>Text 1234567</label> <img src="http://admin.visistat.com/sales/img/icon-pulse-dot-red.png" width="22" height="22" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

--

The **label** tag, **width**, and **float** values did the trick.

Comment: Np, and vote up my answer when you reach rep 15 :) good luck with your projects.